# Need to generate a new text file and save it every time I run a script in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have a program that appends to an already existing file called "ConcentrationData.txt". However, I would like to create a new text file every time the program is run, preferably with a file name that has the date and time. This is what my current script looks like:

```
def measureSample(self):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    freqD1, trandD1, absoD1 = dev.getMeasurement(LED_TO_COLOR='D1'])
    freqD2, trandD2, absoD2 = dev.getMeasurement(LED_TO_COLOR='D2'])
    absoDiff= absoD1 - absoD2
    Coeff= 1 
    Conc = absoDiff/Coeff
    Conc3SD = '{Value:1.{digits}f'.format(Value = Conc, digits=3)
    self.textEdit.clear()
    self.textEdit.setText('Concentration is {0}'.format(Conc3SD))

    timeStr = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
    outFile = open('ConcentrationData.txt','a')
    outFile.write('{0} || Concentration: {1}'.format(timeStr, Conc3SD))
    outFile.close()
```

How would I go about doing that?

(Also, I'm pretty new to python so I'm sorry if this sounds like a silly question).

Comment: How about opening fiile in `w` mode `outFile = open('ConcentrationData.txt','w')` and instead of having a constant string for file name use something like `filename = "{0}.{1}".format("Data.txt",timeStr)`

Comment: If I change it to "w", I get a file with one concentration value. If I keep it on "a", I am able to maintain all of the concentration values that I measured when I used the program as opposed to just one. That is why I would like to create multiple files, instead of just one that append every concentration value that was measured.

Comment: I would suggest to open the file only once for the life of the program or instance depending on your design with `w` mode and close it when the program ends, rather than opening and closing each time you enter the function and like you suggested have different filename make them unique by probably adding a timestamp 
`filename = "{0}.{1}".format("Data.txt",timeStr)`
Opening and closing a file multiple times would also create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Is there any way you might be able to write this for me? I understand what you're saying, but I'm having a difficult time translating that into code. So it's

Comment: is measureSample a instance method of a class , I see a self in your definition ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I created a gui using qt designer. The interface has three buttons: connect, calibrate, and measure. This section is what I want the program to do when the "measure" button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something on the lines of the following

```
class my_class:
   _data_fd = None

   def __init__(self,create,filename):
       if(create):
           self._data_fd = open(filename,'w')

   def __del__(self):
       if(self._data_fd != None):
           self._data_fd.close()

   def measureSample(self):
       ##do something here
       outFile = self._data_fd
       outFile.write('{0} || Concentration: {1}'.format(timeStr, Conc3SD))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    timeStr = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y_%H_%M_%S_%Z') #use unerscore instead of spaces
    filename = "{0}.{1}".format("Data.txt",timeStr)
    imy_class = my_class(1,filename)
    imy_class.measureSample()
    imy_class.measureSample() ##call multiple times the fd remains open for the lifetime of the object
    del imy_class   ### the file closes now and you will have multiple lines of data
```